# Vue.js - changing elements when I don't know how many there will be

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am coming from having used jQuery for a long time and now I am trying to switch to Vue.js. I have a list of posts that I am fetching from a database table and I need to perform some actions when I click on each of the posts. I do not know how many posts there will be, it could be 1000 or  10,000 posts. It seemed easy to do it with jQuery but how would I do this with Vue.js?

When a post is clicked

1. The clicked element's background color changes to red
2. The element inside with a class "bell-icon" gets added "shaking" class
3. Lastly, I show a bell modal that has the id of "#bell-modal"

Here is how I made it with jQuery. P.S. I am using the Laravel framework.

**PHP / HTML**

```
$rows = Posts::all();

@foreach($rows as $row)
    <div class="row">

        {{ $row->name }}
        <span class="ring-bell">
            <i class="material-icons bell-icon bell-id-{{ $row->id }}">ring_bell</i>
        </span>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Javascript**

```
$( ".ring-bell" ).click(function() {
    var bell_id = $( this ).data("bell-id");

    $( this ).css( "background-color", "blue" );
    $(".bell-id-" + bell_id).addClass("shaking");
    $("#bell-modal").show();
});
```

Comment: What have you tried and what specifically are you having trouble with? (post that here to to improve the quality of your question). I think the vue tutorials are adequate to answer this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

It ends up looking something like this:

javascript part of vue:

```
data:{
  posts:[] // all of your posts as a JSON object...
}
methods:{
  myMethod:function(){...}
}
```

html:

```
<div @click="myMethod" v-for="(p,index) in posts" :key="index">
```